# How can I tell if my upgrade is hung?

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, hyper-v

I am fairly new to Linux, but am an experienced IT person.

I have Ubuntu 14.10 installed as a Virtual Machine on Windows Server 2012 R2 running Hyper-V.

I am attempting to update to Ubuntu 15.04.  The update has been sitting on this line for about 1 1/2 hours.  I have a screenshot, but not the reputation to post it.  If warranted, maybe someone can give me a couple upvotes and I can edit this post to add the screenshot.

The screenshot shows several lines of information as the upgrade started to run.  Here are the last three:

```
[  840.027302] INFO: task systemd-udevd:1810 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  840.028304]       Not tainted 3.16.0-33-generic #44-Ubuntu
[  840.029329] "echo 0> /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message
```

My Question is, is this normal or has the upgrade stalled?  If it is not normal/stalled, how to I properly exit the upgrade and restart the upgrade?

Thank you in advance for your help!